# How do I query for all rows but limit by max values of two columns when 3rd column is of a specific value in one single query?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max

```
ID     Type     MovieYear      MovieName    BookName       BookGenre     SongName     SongYear     SongMonth
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Book     null           null         The Hobbit     Fantasy       null          null        null
2      Movie    2019           It           null           null          null          null        null   
3      Song     null           null         null           null          Desperado     2019        11
4      Song     null           null         null           null          Desperado     2019        7
5      Song     null           null         null           null          Away          2000        6
6      Song     null           null         null           null          Away          1988        10
```

Given the data above, I need to be able make a single query.  If type is *not* 'Song' then I want to get everything of those non-song types, and if type *is* 'Song,' then I want to get only those rows that contain each unique 'SongName' but get the Max 'SongYear' and also the Max 'SongMonth'

I want my results to be:

```
ID     Type     MovieYear      MovieName    BookName       BookGenre     SongName     SongYear     SongMonth
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Book     null           null         The Hobbit     Fantasy       null          null        null
2      Movie    2019           It           null           null          null          null        null   
3      Song     null           null         null           null          Desperado     2019        11
5      Song     null           null         null           null          Away          2000        6
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID FROM mytable
    WHERE (songname, songyear, songmonth) IN (
         SELECT songname, max(songyear), max(songmonth)
         FROM (
                  SELECT songname, songyear, songmonth
                  FROM mytable
                  WHERE type = 'Song'
                  GROUP BY songname, songyear, songmonth
         )
         GROUP BY songname
    )
)
```

Obviously this query is very convoluted and very slow, and it also does not take into account the need to also get Book and Movie types in this single query.  Any ideas on what type of query I should try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm . . . I think `row_number()` does this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by type, songname order by songyear desc, songmonth desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where type <> 'Song' or seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This works great, and answers my question.  I'll mark this as answer, but I have a follow up question.  Once I have this resultset, if I try and do any additional filtering the additional where clauses slow the query down considerably.  Is this just a byproduct of partition, or is it possible to improve speeds somehow?